Item is not updating in web index after publish
In my application, the Sitecore publishing service (SPS) is configured. But I want to configure some other way by which I can publish content to web db, so created a custom publish.
In custom publish used Sitecore in-built publishing, by using the below code
var publishOptions = new PublishOptions(itemNotNull.Database, targetDb, publishMode, languages[0], DateTime.Now);

// Create a publisher with the publishoptions 
var publisher = new Publisher(publishOptions, languages);

publisher.Options.RootItem = itemNotNull;
publisher.Options.Deep = @checked;
publisher.Publish();

The above code item is getting published to web db, but not updating in web index.
Whereas when I publish same item with Sitecore Publishing Service (SPS) it appears in web index.
Any hint why this is happening?

issue is solved now thanks

When using Sitecore Publishing Service, you can use Publish Manager to publish item directly as below.
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using System;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Publishing;


var publishOptions = new PublishOptions(itemNotNull.Database, targetDb, publishMode, languages[0], DateTime.Now);
publishOptions.RootItem = item;
publishOptions.Deep = deepPublish;

PublishManager.Publish(publishOptions);

You don't need to instantiate Publish Manager. Directly using Publish Manager as mentioned above can be used for achieving desired output.
Hope this helps!!!

PublishManager uses the SPS service to publish items. I wan to use sitecore in built publishing option so used publisher.publish method

@AnekarVishal Are you using Publish mode as full while creating publish options.Can you check..

Publish mode is smart

@AnekarVishal Can you try changing to Full once and check...

When you use the Sitecore Publishing Service you can't just instantiate a new Publisher() object. You need to use the PublishManager to kick it off. You can call it like this:
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using System;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Publishing;
 
PublishOptions publishOptions = new PublishOptions(item.Database, Database.GetDatabase("web"), publishMode, item.Language, DateTime.Now);
publishOptions.RootItem = item;
publishOptions.Deep = deepPublish;
publishOptions.PublishRelatedItems = publishRelatedItems;
publishOptions.CompareRevisions = compareRevisions;
 
var handle = PublishManager.Publish(new PublishOptions[] { publishOptions });
PublishManager.WaitFor(handle);

See this blog post for reference: https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2019/09/13/sitecore-publish-items-using-the-publishmanager/

PublishManager uses the SPS service to publish items. I wan to use sitecore in built publishing option so used publisher.publish method

You can't mix Publishing Service and standard publishing. You havs SPS, so you need to use it via code to publish.
